# How do you let Ubuntu know you've uninstalled rbenv?

Tags: rbenv

After I  uninstalled rbenv from Ubuntu, every time I open the terminal I get this message:

```
The program 'rbenv' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rbenv
```

How should I remove this message?

Comment: You have a setup somewhere, probably via ~/.bashrc that is trying to call that program.

Comment: How to remove that line from my terminal?

Answer (score 5):

Part of [the rbenv initialization](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout) occurs in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile (or one of the similar start-up scripts). Typically those lines are at the bottom of the script. Read the above page for more information and what to look for.

Remove those lines that try to initialize rbenv and you should be fine.